# How to show output of an SQL query in Sharepoint 2013 web part?

Tags: 2013, javascript, web-part, sql

Is it possible to use the SQL query that I have written and outputted to a web part through JS and display it as a table in a SharePoint 2013 web part?

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly query a database in JavaScript. Among other things it would expose the connection details. You have two options:

1. Build a server side .NET web part.
2. Build a secure web service, hosted somewhere in your network, and call that from your JavaScript.